# How to implement feature like Gmail mail Map this feature

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-api, gmail-api

Does anybody know google provide the gmail mail `Map this` feature API. I researched a lot but didn't find desired result. I want the google API on which i give the string message like

```
BREA PROBLEM F:830 N MAIN ST 46, MT ANGEL:R454, 
MED23:MAP-2530C:57YOF/ C/DIFFB  BEE STING:BAVARIAN VILLAGE    503 845-2586::
```

and goole return me the result same as it user for Map this

```
830 N MAIN ST
MT ANGEL, OR

(http://maps.google.com/maps?q=830+N+MAIN+ST+MT+ANGEL,+OR&oi=gmail)
```

here is the image to understand my question 
[image]

Comment: @Downvoter: Will you mind to write a comment, why?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) to do this lookup. For example, performing the following query returns a json object with a "formatted_address" field containing the re-written address you're looking for. Of course you need to replace `API_KEY` with an API key from your Developer Console project.

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=API_KEY